# Get the current location inside Power App mobile app without internet access, and send it to SharePoint once we get an internet access

Tags: .net, gps, offline, powerapps, offline-mode

Can i get the current location inside Power App mobile app without internet access, and send it to SharePoint once we get an internet access
3 seconds ago

I am trying to implement this scenario :-

1. User access power app inside their mobile (IOS or android). this can be done with or without internet access
2. Click on send my location.
3. Once there is internet access >> the power app will send the location to SharePoint list.

So can we achieve this using power Apps? specifically the ability to get the current location even without internet access? and save it offline to be sent to SharePoint once there is an internet?

Thanks